# How to refactor try-catch with logging in abstract class?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have code sample:

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
  try
  {
    return Convert(value);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    logger.LogError(ex);
    throw new Exeption("Can't convert to type {0}", type);
  }
}
```

How to refactor this one.
I can't remove throw because method must return type. But new exception will hide original one.

Comment: Your code does not compile... can you share the code which is we at least does not have any compilation errors?

Comment: You could add the original exception as inner exception. Then you won't lose information about the stack trace.

Comment: Assign the result of `Convert` to a variable, then return it after `try/catch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue you should use the keyword "throw" alone.

```
    try
    {
        return Convert(value);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex);
        throw;
    }
```

In that way the same exception as the one you received will be thrown again and you will keep all the stack trace.